# Capybara conditional element css rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scroll, rspec, capybara

I have a test in rspec/capybara that checks whether an element is visible on the page. It does fail, when it searches for an element, that is visible only after a scroll on parent element. This element is displayed randomly, one time in visible area right away and sometimes you have to scroll.

How do I include this conditional scroll into test?

```
open_scrollable_element
expect(grid.root_element).to have_content(content)
```

Can i have it something like

```
open_scrollable_element
if expect fails
  scroll_down
  check_again_if_its_visible
```

or what my approach here should be?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of Capybaras has_xxx? Methods for this

```
el=open_scrollable_element
scroll_down if el.has_no_css?('selector for desired element')
expect(grid.root_element).to have_content(content)
```

If the behavior triggered by open_scrollable_element takes a while to actually open the element (loads via ajax or something) then it's possible has_no_css? would match immediately, in that case you can do

```
el=open_scrollable_element
scroll_down unless el.has_css?('selector for desired element')
expect(grid.root_element).to have_content(content)
```

This appears very similar but has a different behavior.  has_no_css? will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the condition to become true, but return as soon as it is.  This means that if the css isn't on the page when it's run it will return immediately.   By doing has_css? instead it will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the page to have the css.  In the case of the css not appearing that means it will wait the full Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds before returning, and then calling scroll_down.   If you want to adjust the amount of time it waits for the call you can pass a  :wait option to the call like

```
el.has_css?('selector', wait: 2)
```

Comment: Well, it is weird, but... element's css becomes visible inside expect, before it has no value.

Comment: Marcin: I'm sorry,  I don't understand what you mean by that comment - the expect(grid.root_element).to have_content(content) will wait (up to a default maximum time) for the content to appear, is the content not appearing? is it not waiting long enough? Maybe posting some html would help, or please more clearly explain the issue you're having.

Comment: Tom: When i did `binding.pry` before expect, element (pop-up list, like tooltip) wasn't shown. It was shown when expect was run.

Comment: Marcin: I would guess that you're loading the content of the element via an ajax request.  Having the binding.pry immediately after after the open_scrollable_element call can block the request from being processed -- if you did   sleep 3; binding.pry  you'd probably see the element.  The have_content matcher and the has_no_css? call will both wait for up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time (was default_wait_time before Capybara 2.5) seconds for their conditions to become true but has_no_css? would match immediately - I'm adding more to my answer to show another way.